# React computer lose ability to update after a duplicated component gets removed

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Fairly new to Reactjs.

```
<div id="divA">
  <Mycomponent id="comA" value={this.props.intValue}/>
</div>
.
.
<div id="divC">
  <Mycomponent id="comB" value={this.props.intValue}/>
</div>
```

In a above code example, I have a component showing on the page twice, and it should render the same infomation, but once 'divA' gets swapped with another component, the "MyComponent" with id "comB" stopped rendering the update for this.props.intValue. What would have caused this issue?

Comment: if you are creating components by `map()` or any loops, make sure are setting unique `key` to your elements.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example? It's unclear from your post...

Comment: I think I narrowed down the issue, it was the library that my component is trying to wrap, https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/dnLLgm5o/ . Similar to this jfiddle, once 'comA' gets removed, some how 'comB' value get cleared out. even I have tried Emad's suggestion, with unique keys.


Checked my props tree, it still have the correct value, even tried console.log inside the component, it still remember the props but the animation get reset to the beginning.. In other words, once 'comA' removed, the component's animation get reset to beginning and not responding to the new values anymore.